# procfile got created twice in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, procfile

I created a Procfile for my rails app. When I commit the change to github I can see that 2 Procfiles are there. One is the one I created `Procfile` and the other `Procfile~`(This one was hidden). I can see that the contents are same when I check on remote repository. Is it normal or should I delete one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one `Procfile`. Usually a file finished with a tilde `~` is a backup copy made by your editor.

The systems relying on the Procfile will just look at the one with that name, they won't care about `Procfile~`, so it's up to you if you want to delete it or not.

A common thing to do is to add the following in your `.gitignore`:

`*~`

Comment: I think you are right as rubymine not showing the ~ version. I will add it to my gitignore file I think..Thanks

Comment: Sure, check my edited answer to what is common to do in your gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

On many unix based systems, a tilde is added to a filename when a temporary save is made in order to avoid data loss and concurrent editings of a single file. If the contents are the same, you can probably delete `Procfile~`.